# Using inline text in textbox not replacing

Tags: asp.net, inline

Is it possible to use inline code to render dynamic text in a text box? I have tried the below but it prints the whole block in the text box.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="FirstName" ValidationGroup="" text='<%="test"%>' ></asp:TextBox>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where are you generating this dynamic text?

Comment: the dynamic text will be coming out of an RESX file and the block looks like this <%=LocalizeString("lblFirstName")%>

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<input type="text" value="<%=test%>" />
```

Comment: unfortunately for me this still prints the whole block as a string

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that you used a standard input field and not a asp.net textbox control. Yes this does work as prescribed but I do require the use of asp.net controls